# why doesn't append in python work properly?

Tags: python, list

```
def get_next_state_for_x(list, next_state):
    final = []
    state = list
    for g in range (len(next_state)):
        temp = state[g]
        state[g] = next_state[g]
        print(state)
        final.append(state)
        state[g] = int(temp)
    print(final)
get_next_state_for_x([0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1])
```

so while i compile this code i get the output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

instead of (for the last line)

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

why does final.append(state) add wrong list to the result ?

Comment: `state` is the same list every time through the loop.

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in class/function.

Comment: Use `final.append(state.copy())`

Comment: Ok I will try it

Comment: thanks a lot it worked

Comment: @PiotrekSzymański, you can make generator function and use `next()` which will be a bit more "pythonic".

Answer (score 2):

You're linking the list, so it changes everytime. You have to copy it

Correct to:

```
final.append(state.copy())
```

So:

```
def get_next_state_for_x(list, next_state):
    final = []
    state = list
    for g in range (len(next_state)):
        temp = state[g]
        state[g] = next_state[g]
        print(state)
        final.append(state.copy())
        state[g] = int(temp)
    print(final)
get_next_state_for_x([0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```